# Problems with compilation

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This is the compiler error that I'm getting:

JogarLightmare.java:105: error:  expected

```
    public static void imprimeCaminho(int posMonius, int posOutro, int linhas, int colunas, int fim){
                                                                  ^
```

JogarLightmare.java:105: error: not a statement

```
    public static void imprimeCaminho(int posMonius, int posOutro, int linhas, int colunas, int fim){
                                                                       ^
```

JogarLightmare.java:105: error: ';' expected

```
    public static void imprimeCaminho(int posMonius, int posOutro, int linhas, int colunas, int fim){
                                                                             ^
```

JogarLightmare.java:105: error:  expected

```
    public static void imprimeCaminho(int posMonius, int posOutro, int linhas, int colunas, int fim){
                                                                                           ^
```

JogarLightmare.java:105: error: not a statement

```
    public static void imprimeCaminho(int posMonius, int posOutro, int linhas, int colunas, int fim){
                                                                                                ^
```

JogarLightmare.java:105: error: ';' expected

```
    public static void imprimeCaminho(int posMonius, int posOutro, int linhas, int colunas, int fim){
```

---

---

---

This is the method in question. I've already verified { } but I don't know where is the problem:

```
public static void imprimeCaminho(int posMonius, int posOutro, int linhas, int colunas, int fim){

      char z = '_';
      char m = 'M';
      char o = 'O';
      char a = '@';

      if(fim == 2){
        o = '*';
      }

      StringBuilder caminho = new StringBuilder(int colunas);

      for(int j = 1; j <= linhas; j = j + 1){
        for(int i = 1; i <= colunas; i = i + 1){

          if(i != posMonius && i != posOutro){
            caminho.append(z);
          }else{

            if(i == posMonius && i == posOutro){
              caminho.append(a);
            }else{

               if(i == posMonius){
                 caminho.append(m);
               }else{
                  caminho.append(o);

                }
             }
           }

        }

        if(j % 2 == 0){
          System.out.println(caminho.reverse().toString());
        }else{
          System.out.println(caminho.toString());
         }

      }

    }
```

Comment: the only issue i can see is the `new StringBuilder(int colunas);` other than that i can't see any other syntax problems.

Comment: the problem might very well be outside this function if you missed a `;` or `)` or `}` somewhere.

Comment: i think @luk2302 is right, just remembered something...

Comment: @luk2302 my guess was wrong but i will check other functions.

Comment: @Aominè what could be wrong? (colunas is as int initialized with a fixed valued)

Comment: @Silver it should be `new StringBuilder(colunas);` and not `new StringBuilder(int colunas);`. what IDE are you using?

Comment: Methods can't exist on their own, they need to be in a class.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I no longer have compiler erros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
StringBuilder caminho = new StringBuilder(int colunas);
```

with this line:

```
StringBuilder caminho = new StringBuilder(colunas);
```

The thing is that the syntax `new StringBuilder(int colunas);` is not valid. `int colunas` is usually used to declare a variable of type `int`, but here you accept this variable as a parameter which doesn't need to specify type again. The variable itself was already declared in this line:

```
public static void imprimeCaminho(int posMonius, int posOutro, int linhas, int colunas, int fim){
```